# Переопределение представления LocalTime в springdoc

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi

Столкнулся с проблемой представления **LocalTime** в swagger(использую springdoc).

To, что было изначально:

Dto, где возникла проблема:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class SessionDto {

    private Long sessionID;

    private Long filmID;

    private Long chatID;

    private Long organizerID;

    private LocalTime stopTime;

}
```

Начальное представление этого dto в swagger:

[image: начальное представление этого dto в swagger]

После прочтения [этого](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/946) issue мне удалось избавиться от объектного представления LocalTime. Для этого я создал такую конфигурацию:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    static {
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithClass(LocalTime.class, String.class);
    }
}
```

Представление dto после добавления конфигурации:

[image: представление dto после добавления конфигурации]

Но кроме всего этого, я хочу, чтобы вместо "string" в качестве примера значения поля stopTime отображалось что-то типа "00:00:00"(В идеале текущее время). Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Решил проблему следующим конфигом:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    static {
        var schema = new Schema<LocalTime>();
        schema.example(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")));
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalTime.class, schema);
    }
}
```